# How to separate commndline arguments on bash scripting on Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, remote-access

In my bash script I want to change file permissions on a particular file called "test.txt" which is located at :

```
"/var/www/tomcat7/dir1/test.txt"
```

My question is if I'm giving this full path to the file, I want to make change the permission on all the directories like, "var", "www", tomcat7", "dir1", and finally "test.txt".

File path is given via a separate text file as command-line arguments, and here is my code,

```
setFilePErmission(){
    ssh ppuser@10.101.5.91 "sudo chmod 777 $1"
}

setFilePErmission $1
```

Can anyone help me? Thank You.... :)

Comment: In this case you can do `chmod -R 777 /var` and all the hierarchy below will get this change done.

Comment: Hello @fedorqui i want to give the file path at once and need to set permission on all the directories which includes.

Comment: What I mean is that if you use `-R` (recursive), `chmod` in `/var` will automatically chmod in all directories inside `/var`, so you won't have to do `chmod /var/www` and then `chmod /var/www/tomcat7/` and so on.

Comment: Why would you want to give such permission? 

The solution which is told by fedorqui will make everything under /var with 777 permission it will include www and any other dir under /var like /var/log as well and same 777 permissions for all other subdir and files under /var. If you do not have issue with then you can procced with chmod -R 777 /var else you will have to find another way.

Comment: @Jord as u told that is a problem actually, so is there any specific way to proceed permission on selected path only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash 
setFilePErmission(){  
i=$(echo "$1" | awk -F '/' '{print NF}') 
y=$1 
while [[ $i -gt 1 ]] 
do 
ssh ppuser@10.101.5.91 "sudo chmod 777 $y" 
y=${y%/*} 
(( i-- )) 
done
}

setFilePErmission "your path goes here"
```

Check if this works for you.

I am still doubtful, why would one need such permissions..

Please be sure while running such thing because once you change permission it will be very difficult to get them to previous values unless you dont remember each and every file permissions.